# What is the recommended way to build "Stripe-subscriptions-checkout" inside app using React Native?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am following this doc https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout.
Is there any way, I can use directly some components from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native or I have to go with Webview only?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stitch together a few different guides from the Stripe docs:

a/ Subscription creation steps happen on your backend, so you perform steps 1 through 5 here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements#install-setup

The rest of that guide uses Stripe Elements, which you won't be using, you'll be substituting it out for ReactNative.

By step 5 in that doc, you'll have created a Subscription (in `status "incomplete"` and you'll need to pay its first PaymentIntent to move the Subscription to `status: "active"`)

b/ Integrate `CardField` or `CardForm` in ReactNative by following this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=custom

This doc shows you server-side snippets for a one-time payment, ignore those as you already have done step 1/.

Integrate the ReactNative client-side code from that guide and at step 4/, you'll confirm the PaymentIntent's `client_secret` from a/ above.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Checkout (Your first link) is a very different thing to Stripe React Native (The library you use to add payment UI elements within your application).

Stripe [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout):

- Is a hosted website (at checkout.stripe.com) your customer gets redirected to to complete a purchase by entering their address, payment method data, etc.
- Is somewhat, but not very customizable.

Stripe [React Native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native):

- Is one of Stripe's SDKs offering UI elements and functions in your native code
- Offers you elements to add to your application

These two methods to integrate Stripe are different to each other, Checkout cannot be shown inside your app, you'll need to use a WebView.

In your case, I recommend you follow [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native) instead of the Checkout one to use the React Native elements and SDK.

Comment: This is an onetime payment. I want subscriptions.